# onSaveInstanceState() is not working after process death on Huawei P20 (EMUI 10)

Tags: android, huawei-developers

`onSaveInstanceState()` is not working if system-initiated process death has occurred on Huawei P20 (EMUI 10). In the case of a configuration change, everything works as described in the android specification.

The easiest way to reproduce this:

1. Create app with one activity with one text field
2. Launch the app and type some text in the text field
3. Launch another app (don't close the first app)
4. Repeat step (3) several time until the device memory becomes insufficient for the first application
5. Switch to the first app
6. See that the text field does not contain the previously typed text

I did the same with the android emulator (Android 10) but typed text was restored on it. It seems that huawei does not conform to the android spec. I think that this problem is only with huawei because it is reproduced on huawei p20 and honor 10 but not on emulator and my LG tablet.

Comment: If you use `adb shell am kill ...` (where `...` is your application ID), do you get the same effect? Or, does the saved instance state work correctly in that case?

Comment: @CommonsWare this command does nothing but `adb shell am force-stop ...` works. But saved instance state does not work correctly with it

Comment: OK, at least the behavior is consistent. Since your code is working elsewhere, it would appear that Huawei screwed something up. Only their international devices that ship with the Play Store would need to pass the Compatibility Test Suite, and I would expect that this functionality is tested there.